# XMLWriter in C# Anyway around hexidecimal character exception?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm making a world editor for a game in C# XNA.

The file contains a large sum of data so I feel XmlWriter is necessary.

The application runs perfectly fine. Files are saved in a directory which they're immediately accessible in, however, for the file to load directly into the pipeline it's necessary to include the line

```
<Asset Type = ObjectID.objectID[]>
```

Unfortunately this includes hexidecimal characters not supported by XmlWriter, XDocument and XmlDocument so I'm wondering if there's a way around it or perhaps there's an xml type I've not tried that allows odd hexidecimal characters.

If there isn't, that's quite alright as I've a back-up plan, but I'm just wondering.
Thank you kindly for the read and I hope my question is well written. :)

Comment: Which characters? Not all characters are legal in XML 1.1, and XML 1.0 was more restrictive. See the XML Recommendations for details.

Comment: You can enclose `ObjectID.objectID[]` in single quotes like `<Asset Type = 'ObjectID.objectID[]'>`

Comment: Spaces, equals, quotation marks, fullstops, square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was able to use WriteRaw to write the line as a raw string, though this breaks the file format :(

```
writer.WriteRaw("<Asset Type = \"objectID.objectID[]>\"");
```

Sorry to be the one to answer my own question but thanks for the support all the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<XnaContent><Asset Type = "objectID.objectID[]>"<Item><ID>2</ID><xPos>640</xPos><yPos>280</yPos>    <xPath>0</xPath><yPath>0</yPath></Item></Asset></XnaContent>
```